# Google Drive OAuth 2 flow giving invalid_scope error

Tags: google-drive-api

My Google Drive app requests the following scopes when exchanging a code for an access token:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
```

In particular, this is the query string of the URL that is eventually being requested from Google during the exchange:

`code=XXXXXXXXXX&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXXXXX& scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file+ https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email +https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile +https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.install &client_id=XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXX`

The response is a 400 error, with the error message "invalid_scope". What am I doing wrong?

**[Edit] Additional information:**

The error only happens when the user clicks through from Google Drive to create a new document. If I initiate the authentication/authorization flow from my own app, the list of scopes is accepted just fine. If the user clicks through the actual Drive app to create a new document, I get invalid_scopes.

**The invalid scope is drive.install**. If I remove that from the list of requested scopes when the user shows up to create a new document, things start working again. Does that make any sense at all? If the user has the Drive app installed already via us requesting that scope, why would requesting that same scope when the user shows up from the Drive app cause a problem of any kind?

Comment: Hi Ben, is this new? I can't reproduce this with the OAuth2 Playground. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground Can you try, please?

Comment: In the OAuth Playground, the POST data doesn't actually include any scopes, and it succeeds: code=4%2FzVoxcbiMw77zguVnfeuiUoGM8gSy.8pi045fH2jofMqTmHjyTFGP0BoOAfQI&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=&client_secret=************&grant_type=authorization_code

Point being, is my Java library wrong? Should I just never pass any scopes to the code exchange process?

Comment: Yes, scopes shouldn't be sent for the code exchange. If it is your own library, please leave that out.

Comment: This is the Google-provided OAuth library (com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2...) It turns out I only get this error with the drive.install scope, not any other scopes. I tried just not sending scopes to the code exchange, but then I got a token with no permissions, as I sort of expected. But by leaving off drive.install, things work again. Am I the only one seeing this behavior?

Comment: @BenDilts, I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Is it possible to provide code snippets?

Answer (score 7):

I experienced a similar problem. The solution was to pass an array of scopes to the google client:

```
google_client.authorization.scope=[
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata']
```

rather than a concatenated string of scopes

```
google_client.authorization.scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly%2Bhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
```

The GET request in the Rails log looked identical, but the result was very different!

Answer (score 4):

There is a chance that You might be using **tab** instead of **space** between two auth like

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata

putted on new line to show tabs

always use one white space between these two links to authorization.

this had happened with me.

Answer (score 1):

The new google api (at the moment of this answer is posted) requires scope attribute to be one string and scopes separated with white space. So like this

```
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send";

gapi.auth2.init({
     client_id:CLIENT_ID,
     scope: SCOPES
}).then (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try not escaping the `+` symbols. That worked for us.